# Converting <audio> currentTime to accurate time display

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to get an audio's current time to display as hours:minutes:seconds (00:00:00) rather than just in 'seconds' or 'minutes and seconds'.  The current code is what I have...

```
<audio id="audio" ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = '0' + Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration); " src="music.mp3"></audio>
```

This displays the seconds as 0 / 0 inside of the following...

```
<span id="tracktime">0 / 0</span>
```

I have searched for hours and all of the solutions I have found are simply doing nothing.

I even found the following code to assist but am not sure how to implement this into the 'ontimeupdate' action in the audio tag.

```
var minutes = '0' + Math.floor(currentTime / 60); var seconds = '0' + (currentTime - minutes * 60); var cur = minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
```

If possible, I would like it to display as two seperate items.  Like so...

```
<div id="currentTime"></div>
<div id="duration"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample how you can do

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var cur = document.querySelector('#cur'),
      dur = document.querySelector('#dur')
      vid = document.querySelector('#aud')
})
    
aud.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
  cur.textContent = "Current: " + sToTime(e.target.currentTime);
  dur.textContent = "Duration: " + sToTime(e.target.duration);
})

function sToTime(t) {
  return padZero(parseInt((t / (60 * 60)) % 24)) + ":" +
         padZero(parseInt((t / (60)) % 60)) + ":" + 
         padZero(parseInt((t) % 60));
}
function padZero(v) {
  return (v < 10) ? "0" + v : v;
}
```

```html
<audio id="aud" controls>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p id="cur"></p>
<p id="dur"></p>
```

Comment: Well, this question was pertaining to "audio", not "video".  And of course, even after playing with the code to try and get it to work for <audio>, it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @user2284703 Updated to an `audio` element. Does this one play for you here at SO? ... If no, what browser do you use?

Comment: note: sToTime doesn't return "00:00:00" at the start of the clip if the number of seconds is too small (e.g. 0.002). In this case, `parseInt` returns scientific notation, and you get a non 0 number for hours. At the start of the function, I added `if(t < 1) return "00:00:00";`

Comment: @Emil If you need _decimal_, use `parseFloat`

Comment: @LGSon you misinterpreted what I said. If currentTime is too small (like 0.002), parseInt will give you scientific notation, and your hours number might be wrong. I retrieved current time before pressing play, and it was 0.002, and the function made calculations on scientific notation, which is wrong.

Comment: @Emil I obviously did :) ... now I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function formatDuration(seconds: number) {
      return new Date(1000 * seconds).toISOString().slice(11, 19)
    }
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.